# How to sort by 2 columns and keep the top row from each group created?

Tags: text-processing, osx, sort

I have two csv file of the following format:

```
column1,column2,user,column4,column5,column...column14
```

I would like to sort the files based on user as first key and then based on column14 in descending order which is a number representing a timestamp.

The result would be like:

file1:

```
A,AA,jim,XX,YY,....,1485771395    
A,AA,jim,XX,YY,....,1485771395
```

etc

I would like then from these files to keep only the first row of each cluster i.e. only

```
A,AA,jim,XX,YY,....,1485771395
```

How can I do that?

**Update:**
Example input:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295      
"1/26/2017 5:06:11 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485403571  
"1/26/2017 8:02:01 PM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485457321  
"1/30/2017 4:14:30 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485746070  
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976  
"1/30/2017 11:14:50 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771290      
"1/22/2017 11:51:51 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485082311
```

The last column is the epoch of the first column to be able to sort the rows using a number instead of a string.
So the expected output would be:
a) Sorting on name and on timestamp in reverse order so we get:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295    
"1/30/2017 11:14:50 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771290        
"1/26/2017 8:02:01 PM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485457321  
"1/26/2017 5:06:11 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485403571  
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976  
"1/30/2017 4:14:30 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485746070  
"1/22/2017 11:51:51 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485082311
```

So we have a cluster of rows for `jim.smith` another for `tim.jones` sorted by the last column in reverse order (i.e. the latest date of the first row is first in the cluster) and a row for `john.doe` that has only 1 record.

Then I would like to keep only the first row of each cluster. I.e.

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295    
"1/26/2017 5:06:11 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485403571    
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976
```

Comment: @don_crissti:I don't want the first line of the file. I am sorting on 2 columns and I will get groups in the cases that the first column has more than one occurrence. I want the top line of each group.

Comment: `sort -u` or `uniq`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti:How would that help? I am interested in the line with the max timestamp per user

Comment: So really you don't need to *sort* on the 14th field - except as a step to obtaining the max? Can you give us a dataset that is at least large enough to test (i.e. actually has at least one user with at least two different values of $14)

Comment: ... something like `sort -t, -k3,3 -k14,14n file.csv | awk -F, '!seen[$3]++'` maybe?

Comment: Have you tried something? I mean you haven't provided any script, any test data...

Comment: @steeldriver:The $14 is just the epoch i.e. it is the same as '2017-01-01 12:20 AM' So by sorting descending I would get users sorted by name and for users with more than one row I would sort them by that timestamp in reverse order. So it would be `jim,,,,,2017-01-01 12:20 AM\njim,,,,,2017-01-01 10:20 AM` and I would like to keep only `jim,,,,,2017-01-01 12:20 AM\n`

Comment: @ka3ak:See previous comment on more details. I am trying to avoiding writing a script. I would like a bash solution if possible

Comment: Did you try the `sort . . . | awk` suggestion I posted? **I** can't test it, because you haven't given us a usable test case

Comment: @steeldriver:Please see update OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given file `input` as

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295      
"1/26/2017 5:06:11 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485403571  
"1/26/2017 8:02:01 PM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485457321  
"1/30/2017 4:14:30 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485746070  
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976  
"1/30/2017 11:14:50 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771290      
"1/22/2017 11:51:51 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485082311
```

then

```
sort -t, -k3,3 -k5,5rn input | awk -F, '!seen[$3]++'
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295      
"1/26/2017 5:06:11 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485403571  
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976
```

Comment: +1, but I have a preference for `sort -t, -k3,3 -k5,5rn  input | sort -t, -k3,3 -u`

Comment: How does the awk part work? It evaluates to true only once per user right?

Comment: @iruvar:How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

With [`gnu datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -t, -s -f -g 3 max 5 <infile
```

but note that you need to remove all trailing blanks from each line in your input before running it.
With `awk` only, using two arrays:

```
awk -F, '!z[$3]{x[$3]=$0;z[$3]=$5;next}$5>z[$3]{x[$3]=$0}
END{for (i in z){print x[i]}}' infile
```

Comment: I am on OSX so I think this is not applicable right?

Comment: @Jim - afaik `awk` is available on `osx` , isn't it ?

Comment: I was referring to `datamash`

Comment: @Jim - it's not available on a default `osx` setup but [you can install it via `homebrew`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/download/#osx) so whether it's applicable in your particular case or not - I don't know.