# Remove rows from a file that exist in another file with newer timestamp

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, osx, csv

I have 2 files in the exactly the same format and the same data except for 1 column.
Example row of file 1:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295
```

Example row of file 2:

```
"1/26/2017 8:02:01 PM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485457321
```

Of course the files have other rows but what I am interested in is the following:
I want to remove from file 2 all rows that are about the same entity i.e. `$3` and exist in file 1 with a later timestamp and keep the rest.
In the example lines you can see that the row in file 1 is newer as we see from the date string of column 1. Now the last integer in the row is the actual epoch of column 1 so this column can be used for e.g. comparing the dates and sorting.
I can accomplish this by scripting e.g in perl something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use strict;  
use warnings;  
my $file_a = "file1";
my $file_b = "file2";

open my $file_a_h, $file_a or die "Could not open $file_a";  

sub timestamp_users {  
    my ($fh) = @_;  
    my %recs;   

   while ( my $line =<$fh> ) {    
        my @items = split ",", $line;  
        my $user = $items[3];  
        $recs{$user} = $items[5];    
    }  
    return \%recs;    
}    

my $file_a_recs = timestamp_users($file_a_h);  

close $file_a_h;  

open my $file_b_h, $file_b or die "Could not open $file_b";  

my $file_b_recs = timestamp_users($file_b_h);    
close $file_b_h;  

my $count = 0;
while (my ($user, $last_time) = each %$file_b_recs) {  
    if(exists $file_a_recs->{$user} && $last_time >= $file_a_recs->{$user}) {
        ++$count;  
        `echo $user >> result.txt`;    

    }
}
print "count: $count\n";
```

In this case I just output the users and then I would need to do a `grep -v` on file_b to figure out the rows I need.

But is there a way to do this using command line tools?
This approach seems too complicated for me.

**Update:**

Example row of file 1:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:55 AM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485771295        
"1/26/2017 5:06:11 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485403571    
"1/30/2017 4:14:30 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485746070
```

Example row of file 2:

```
"1/26/2017 8:02:01 PM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485457321    
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976   
"1/30/2017 11:14:03 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485771243  
"1/30/2017 11:13:53 AM",New customer,bill.smith,CA,1485771233
```

Expected output:

```
"1/30/2017 11:14:03 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485771243    
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976   
"1/30/2017 11:13:53 AM",New customer,bill.smith,CA,1485771233
```

Comment: If you've already [done this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342122) with `file1` so for each ID (`$3`) there's just one line in `file1` then you can simply run `awk -F,  'NR==FNR{z[$3]=$5;next}$5>=z[$3]' file1 file2`

Comment: @don_crissti:Yes I have done that pre processing. What does that awk line do?

Comment: Well, it's quite straightforward: it saves the value of `$5` for each `$3` while reading `file1` then it reads `file2` and it prints the line if the condition `$5>=z[$3]` is true (that is if the current `$5` is `ge` than the value of `$5` from `file1` corresponding to the same `$3`) - iow it removes the lines for which that condition is false.

Comment: @don_crissti:So `NR==FNR` is a logical condition then `{z[$3]=$5;next}` is the code block and because we have a second file we can have after the code block another logical condition?

Comment: Just to clear things up: you can have as many conditions as you want... It's the `next` statement that prevents the 2nd condition to be evaluated while processing the 1st file. Basically `NR==FNR` means _as long as `F`ile line `N`umbe`R` is equal to combined/aggregate input line `N`umbe`R`_ (i.e. this condition is true only for the 1st file) do `{something;next}` and `next` skips the commands that follow and reads in the next line, starting from the beginning. So the 2nd condition `$5>=z[$3]` is evaluated only for the lines in 2nd file and when true the default action is executed (print)

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `$5 in z && $5>=z[$3]`? Otherwise we compare different users timestamps right? Also it doesn't print something when I try it? Should there be a code block after `$5>=z[$3]`?

Comment: no, you don't need `$5 in z` (which is wrong anyway, the correct one would be `$3 in z`) because again, you are comparing `$5` of the current `$3` with the value of `$5` in `file1` for the same `$3` which is saved in `z[$3]`; the code works fine here with your input samples although I removed all trailing spaces from the input; and no, there should be nothing after `$5>=z[$3]` because as I said, if there's nothing there `awk` "adds" by default `{print}`

Comment: unless there are IDs in `file2` that don't exist in `file1` in which case yes, you need that condition but negated `!($3 in z)` to print those lines and only check for values if the ID exists in `file1` so `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{z[$3]=$5;next};!($3 in z) || $5>=z[$3]' file1 file2`

Comment: @don_crissti:Yes I see now. BTW I did a typo: `'NR==FNR{z[$3]=$5;next};(!$3 in z) || $5>=z[$3]' file1 file2`. I misplaced the ! but awk did not complaint.

Comment: @don_crissti:Is the `;` needed if I add the `!($3 in z)`? You didn't have it after `next;}` in your first snippet

Comment: Jim, it's not needed with `gnu awk` but other `awk`s might complain (I'm not familiar with all of them).

Answer (score 1):

To get the newest version of each row in both files:

```
$  cat file1 file2 | sort -t',' -k3,3 -k5,5nr | sort -t',' -u -k3,3 -o newest
```

This concatenates the files and sorts the records with the fields from field 3 and 5 as the sorting key. This sorts the concatenated file so that the newest record for each person comes first (thanks to the timestamp in the last column). The last sort uses field 3 as the sorting key and does a unique sort based on this field. This will leave only the newest record for each person in the file `newest`.

Then we create the complement of the lines in `newest`, i.e. all records in the two files that are older than the newest record for each person:

```
$ cat file1 file2 | grep -v -F -x -f newest >older
```

The `grep` does a fixed string match (`-F`) on complete lines (`-x`) and returns all lines not matching (`-v`) anything in `newest`. These lines are stored in `older`.

The last step is to remove any line from `file2` that is present in the `older` file:

```
$ grep -v -F -x -f older file2 >new-file2
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why do `k2r` for sort? The second field is a random string `Valid Customer`. Why sort on that?

Comment: @Jim I've changed it so that it only care about the third and fifth columns. The `-k3,3 -k5,5nr` will sort all the names (`-k3,3`) and then for each name reverse numeric sort on the last field (`-k5,5nr`). I initially thought that all fields except for the first and last one one uniquely identified a person.

Comment: When we run the first snippet `newest` will have the line with the latest timestamp per user but we don't know in which file it exists. Then in the second snippet `older` would contain all the the other rows of the 2 files. But what I am interested in is to keep the rows in file 2 for which either there is no matching user in file 1 or the timestamp if file 1 is older. Somehow I am not sure these 3 commands do this. TBH I understood the first and the second but not all 3 combined as to what they do together

Comment: @Jim There is precious little data to test with in the problem description. If you could add more sample data together with what you'd expect as output, that would make it possible to come up with a solution. Also add the clarification of the problem from your last comment to the actual text in the question.

Comment: Please see updated OP

Comment: @Jim, my answer replicates the desired output, but will generate the result in a slightly different order (first two lines swapped).

Comment: I don't care about the ordering in the output. I don't understand how these 3 commands together create the same output as described though