# Piping sed to grep does not seem to work as expected

Tags: command-line, sed, grep, osx, pipe

I have 2 files:

```
$ cat file1  
jim.smith  
john.doe  
bill.johnson  
alex.smith  

$ cat file2   
"1/26/2017 8:02:01 PM",Valid customer,jim.smith,NY,1485457321      
"1/30/2017 11:09:36 AM",New customer,tim.jones,CO,1485770976     
"1/30/2017 11:14:03 AM",New customer,john.doe,CA,1485771243  
"1/30/2017 11:13:53 AM",New customer,bill.smith,CA,1485771233
```

I want from file2 all the names that do not exist in file1.
The following does not work:

```
$ cut -d, -f 3 file2 | sed 's/"//g' | grep -v file1  
jim.smith  
tim.jones  
john.doe  
bill.smith
```

Why the pipe to grep -v does not work in this case?

Comment: That's... not what `grep -v` does. You are asking for all the names that to not contain the string "file1".

Comment: @Celada:I pipe into grep -v right? So I was expecting that the strings piped in would be the ones to search. Hm. So is there a way for the pipe to work?

Comment: No, the strings piped in are the input to search through. That's what `grep` always does: it copies its input to its output, but only the lines that match (or DO NOT match in this case, because of `-v`) a given pattern.

Comment: Be careful about the extra spaces after the names (if you remove them and `grep -v f file1` it will work

Comment: Jim, if any of the answers, please Accept it by using the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is virtually the last step in my [answer to your earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342487/116858).

Your solution works, if you add `-f` in front of `file1` in the `grep`:

```
$ cut -d, -f3 file2 | grep -v -f file1
tim.jones
bill.smith
```

With the `-f`, `grep` will look in `file1` for the patterns. Without it, it will simply use `file1` as the literal pattern.

You might also want to use `-F` since otherwise, the dot in the pattern will be interpreted as "any character". And while you're at it, put `-x` in there as well to make `grep` perform the match across the whole line (will be useful if you have a `joe.smith` that shouldn't match `joe.smiths`):

```
$ cut -d, -f3 file2 | grep -v -F -x -f file1
```

This requires, obviously, that there are no trailing spaces at the end of the lines in `file1` (which there seems to be in the text in the question).

Note that the `sed` is not needed since the output of the `cut` doesn't contain any `"`. Also, if you had *needed* to remove all `"`, then `tr -d '"'` would have been a better tool.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  No `sed`.  Requires GNU `diff` and `bash`.

```
diff --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" <(cut -f3 -d, file2|sort) <(sort file1)
```

Yields results:

```
bill.smith
tim.jones
```

Comment: Sure, have flipped the order around to meet need.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$ pattern=$(cut -d, -f 3 file2)
$ grep -v -e "$pattern" file1
```

In your example grep misses its pattern. Moreover grep can read either a file or stdin (by pipe) not both. If filename is not given then grep reads from stdin.

Also, this might also work:

```
$ grep -v -f <(cut -d, -f3 file1) file2
```

Sorry, it is not tested.

Comment: Where is the sed?

Comment: or `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{z[$0]++;next}!($3 in z){print $3}' file1 file2` ... really, this has been asked too many times...

Comment: @Jim There is no need for sed in field 3 of file 2, since does not contain `"` char.

Comment: @Jim if you need it anywat can be added in the pattern declaration, just after cut.

Comment: @don_crissti:I want to understand why each case doesn't work even though there is another solution. But thank you for pointing that out and for your help so far

Answer (score 1):

The answer with `grep -f` is probably the best one, but a slightly stylish alternative is:

```
% cut -d, -f3 file2 >names2
% cat file1 file1 names2 | sort | uniq -u
bill.smith
tim.jones
%
```

This does, of course, require an extra temporary file (or fun and games with file descriptors), and I wouldn't want to try it with big files.

I mention this only because, for tasks involving matching between files, `sort` plus `uniq` is an unexpectedly versatile, and perhaps underappreciated, pair of tools.  For quick tasks, they can provide a little-thought-required way to a result.